# How to check broken links in a webpage?

Tags: bash

I maintained a list of links to some resources in my blog.
If I find a link is broken, I add a `class="broken"` to it.
Sometimes the broken links go to alive again, so I remove the `class="broken"`.
When the list goes very long, it's very hard to check them one bye one.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://www.a.com">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.b.com">b</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.c.com" class="broken">c</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.d.com">d</a></li>
</ul>
```

How to write a `bash` script to do the editing?

Comment: A combination of `grep` and `wget`, I would imagine.

Comment: You'd need some RegEx to extract the href="..." part, then pipe to <test-tool>, then substitute with class=broken. I think even if maybe Bash can do this, it wouldn't be very robust. If it's just a game that's ok, otherwise I'd go with another language

Comment: see if below links helps you...

http://giantdorks.org/alain/little-shell-script-to-recursively-check-a-site-for-broken-links/

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/writingscripts.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's not the answer you're looking for, but why doing it from bash, and not writing the page to use javascript that can do it on request basis / on the fly? This should get you going http://www.egrappler.com/jquery-broken-link-checker-plugin-jslink/

but I think it would be also possible to create similar logic on your own with jQuery $.get / $.load methods

Answer (score 0):

Not quite appropriate task for Bash.

- Option 1: I'd use Java or Groovy, have a SAX handler simply dump all data to output, except for the `<a>` elements for which it would check the `href` value, and if broken, add the `class="broken"` part.
- Option 2: Have a XSLT which would call a custom XSLT function on `<a>` elements. Again, I'd do this with Java, but any language with a good XSLT engine can do that.
- Option 3: If you really really want to feel geeky ;-) here's a line to get quite unreliable link checker for Bash:

---

```
grep -R '(?:href="(http://[^"]+)")' -ohPI | grep -oP 'http://[^"]+' | sort | uniq |  wget -nv -S -O /dev/null -i - 2>&1 | grep -P '(wget:| -> |HTTP/|Location:)'
```

It could probably get better but I was okay with this.

- Option 4: You could employ `curl -L ...` (the `-L` follows the redirects) instead of `wget`.

---

```
grep -R '(?:"(http://[^"]+)")' -ohPI | grep -v search.maven.org | grep -oP 'http://[^"]+' | sort | uniq |  xargs -I{} sh -c 'echo && echo "$1" && curl -i -I -L -m 5 -s -S "$1"' -- {}  2>&1 | grep -P '(^$|curl:|HTTP/|http://|https://|Location:)'
```

Pro tip: `curl` seems to have more scripting friendly output, so you can make it parallel to speed things up: `... | xargs -n 1 -P 8 curl -L ...` This will run 8 processes of `curl`, and pass one argument (URL) at a time. Sorting out the output is up to you, I'd probably create one file for each `curl` invocation and then concatenated.